# How convert floats into time duration

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a SQL Server table I have two number columns (`float` to be exact):

- `Numberfield_01` has value 3,50
- `Numberfield_02` has value 1,25

These number fields represent hours (European timescale).

`Numberfield_02` stands for 1 hours and a quarter of an hour.

With `SUM` the outcome of these two fields is 4,75 (4 hours and 3 quarters of an hour)

Now I want to convert this outcome of 4,75 into a new field (type float): `04:45` via a `SELECT` statement.

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: "into a new field (type float):04:45" - huh? lovely float.

Comment: take the decimal part, multiply it by 60, then convert the integer part to string and append the minutes.

Comment: If you used the proper datatype (time in this case) you wouldn't have nearly as much problem as you are having. When you get the ddl right the dml is pretty simple.

Comment: I understand, but I am unfortunately "forced" to use the database design of a another supplier

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (Numberfield_01  FLOAT, Numberfield_02 FLOAT)

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (3.50 , 1.25)

SELECT CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(MINUTE, 60*(Numberfield_01 + Numberfield_02), 0))
FROM @TABLE

RESULT : 04:45:00
```

Comment: Somehow I get the error "Operand type clash: time is incompatible with float". Is there a workaround?

Comment: Float is not allowed to convert to time or vice versa. You would have to convert it to varchar and tehn convert. But first you would have to make sure no invalis times were in the table.